# How to echo on same html page after form submit?

Tags: php, html, forms, submit, echo

When the form is submitted, my page is redirected to the PHP and the echo is displayed. How can I display the echo without being redirected to the PHP page? So the echo should be displayed in the html page (where the html form is located).

```
<form method="post" action="../form.php">
<input type="submit" name="1" value="YES" />
<input type="submit" name="1" value="NO" />
</form>
```

-

```
<?php 
$answer = $_POST['1'];  
if ($answer == "YES") {          
    echo 'Good!!!';      
}
else {
    echo 'Try Again!';
} 
?>
```

Comment: is the form and the code to handle it all in the same script (form.php)?

Comment: what do you mean by `form has submitted somewhere on the html page(maybe inside a div or input field)`

Comment: Not exactly sure if I understand what your saying but it sounds like your trying to display something without a page refresh which you could do with AJAX

Comment: When they hit one of the submit buttons, I want to echo a result but not leave the page. How can the echoed message be displayed on the html page where the form is located instead of the PHP? I mean without Ajax. My idea is to send the value from the PHP to an input textfield in the html page. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you can use a combination of `<iframe>` and javascript to get the results.

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php" target="myIframe" >
    <input type="submit" name="1" value="YES" />
    <input type="submit" name="1" value="NO" />
</form>

<iframe name="myIframe">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it on the same page - at least not without asynchronous client-server communication techniques such as AJAX. Otherwise, you can use the following:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ? method=....>"
```

as your form opening tag, then put the PHP processing code at the top of the document, like this:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['form_field_name'])){
       //process your data here
?>

HTML in case of Form filled in goes here

<?php
}else{
?>

HTML in case of Form not filled in goes here

<?php
  }
?>

HTML in any case goes here
```

This way you can change the layout of your page depending on whether the form was filled in or not. the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] contains the reference to the currently requested page, and therefore is always set to the correct page even if it is renamed. This can save you time when bug-tracking.

Comment: I upvoted for the depth of info. I would strongly suggest not having code to draw the form twice. Instead you always display the form and have if clauses to add the "value=" attributes in the form tags.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['1'])){
    echo ($_POST['1'] == 'YES') ? 'Good!!!' : 'Try Again!';
}

?>

<!-- your HTML goes here -->
```

You can combine HTML and PHP on the same page.

Comment: -1 i don't see difference, except there will be no E_NOTICE warning. -1 for no proper explanation

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski To me, this looks like what the OP is asking for.

Comment: It combines the HTML and PHP on the same page, which is what I've understood from the OP.

Comment: @MarcusRecck yeah but same piece of code is in question :] (except there will be no E_NOTICE warning)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" maxlength="30" name="nm">
<input type="email" maxlength="30"  name="em"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox1" value="male">Male
<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox2" value="male">Male
<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox3" value="male">Male
<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox4" value="male">Male
<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox5" value="male">Male
<input type="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo "Welcome :".$_POST['nm']."<br>";
echo "Your email Address is: ".$_POST['em']."<br>";
}
$count=0;
if(isset($_POST['chkbox1']))
$count++;
if(isset($_POST['chkbox2']))
$count++;
if(isset($_POST['chkbox3']))
$count++;
if(isset($_POST['chkbox4']))
$count++;
if(isset($_POST['chkbox5']))
$count++;
echo" Number of checkboxes ticked are:".$count;
?>
```

Comment: Read the question again, @zefs already has this and want other behaviour.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the action to the same page for example:

If I am working on a file called index.php

that will be my form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="Example" placeholder="Enter Text">
```